# Win32 Mouse Click

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, mouseevent, pywin32, win32com

So, this is my code right now:

```
import win32, win32com

def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32com.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    print('Left Click')
```

But when I run it, that's what I get:

> win32api.mouse_event(win32com.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
>   AttributeError: module 'win32com' has no attribute
>   'MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN'

Any idea why?
I'm running Python 3.7 by the way.

Comment: Don't send events one at a time. Put them in an array and send them one shot. Documentation explains why.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `win32con` which contains predefined constants

Also add `import win32api`

```
import win32api, win32con

def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    print('Left Click')

leftClick()
```

Comment: You may also want to explorer UI Automation, with pywinauto for example