# how to make mouse click automatically

Tags: python, yolov5

I use yolo to detect objects
when AI detects the blue bubble, the mouse moves to the blue bubble
How do I make the mouse automatically click on the blue bubble when I hover over the blue bubble

```
def is_click_enabled():
    return True if click_status == colored("ENABLED", 'green') else False

def is_targeted():
    return True if win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) in (-127, -128) else False
```

I tried to use `mouse.click` but it wasn't good

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391564/win32-mouse-click since you are already using win32api

Comment: You can try [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks)

Comment: You would want to do it this way. As mentioned by @It_is_Chris, `pyautogui` is great for mouse controls and you can use it for mouse clicks. Firstly, Yolo returns the normalized coordinates of the detection box. You would need to convert this to standard coordinates by multiplying it with the frame sizes. Next, you would get the positions and move the mouse using `pyautogui.moveTo(x_pos, y_pos)`. After the pointer has shifted to that position, you can click using `pyautogui.click()`. This is the strategy if you are using Yolo.

Comment: The mouse position can be set to the center of the bubble by taking the mean of the `x` and `y` coordinates after converting back from the normalized form.